# UDE Invalid Device Descriptor

Tags: kmdf, wdf

I have been working through Microsoft's guide on [USB Device Emulation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/writing-a-ude-client-driver) and have reached the point that a virtual device shows up in my device manager, but reports an [Invalid Device Descriptor.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wno91.png)

Can you see any reason why the guide's example descriptor might be invalid?

```
//In this example, the descriptor declarations are assumed to be global variables, 
//declared as shown here for a HID device just as an example:
const UCHAR g_UsbDeviceDescriptor[] = {
    // Device Descriptor
    0x12, // Descriptor Size
    0x01, // Device Descriptor Type
    0x00, 0x03, // USB 3.0
    0x00, // Device class
    0x00, // Device sub-class
    0x00, // Device protocol
    0x09, // Maxpacket size for EP0 : 2^9
    0x5E, 0x04, // Vendor ID
    0x39, 0x00, // Product ID 
    0x00, // LSB of firmware version
    0x03, // MSB of firmware version
    0x01, // Manufacture string index
    0x03, // Product string index
    0x00, // Serial number string index
    0x01 // Number of configurations
};
```

Comment: There is a good chance the descriptor is invalid because of a communication issue in my code, but I'm working through the checklist of possible errors.

Comment: Try following the instructions here to see why the stack doesn't like your descriptor: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/capture-and-view-ing-usb-traces-with-microsoft-message-analyzer-